# difference between .dbo and .mdf database

Tags: database

I am really new to database and I am using visual studio 2010. From what I know, there are two ways of creating a database. The first is to right clicked on the project and select Add->New Item and then in the Add New Item dialog I select the Service-based Database which creates a mdf file that lies locally in my project.

Alternatively, I can also create a database in the following way. Right click on the DataConnection in Server Explorer and select Create New SQL Server Database. The created database is shown in server explorer as homepc\sqlexpress.myCreatedDatabase.dbo.

So my question is what is the difference between this two databases (mdf and dbo) and will there be any differences that might occur after I release my project, install and run it on other pcs?

Answer (score 1):

**.DBO** is the database owner while
 **.MDF** is the manifest data file which is the actual database file. 
The primary data file contains the startup information for the database and points to the other files in the database. User data and objects can be stored in this file or in secondary data files. Every database has one primary data file. The recommended file name extension for primary data files is **.mdf**.(*see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189563.aspx)*)

for more info see the forum here [DBO or MDF whats the diffrence?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1259633.aspx/1)

Comment: So if I use any of them they should be able to work after I release the project and run on other pc?