# From hex to date using python or no matter language

Tags: python, date, hex

I have hex file with float data like(-1.9, 241.0, 1.1) and have date, but  don't know in which format! So when I read it in uint32:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
f = open("NV_6_7.dbo", "rb")
f7 = open("7.dbo", "wt")
a = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.uint32)    
for i in a:
    f7.write(str(i))
    f7.write("\n")
```

I have my data only in int format, its no matter now I am interesting in found the Date. So cut of result file something like:

```
 0
 0
 22270201 --------->This is groving up every 5 sec on 7953643 value
 1088734080--------> when 22270201 becomes 4294967295 it counts +1
 273
 87
 51
```

I am feeling that it is date but how to convert\decode it to humanformat I don't know. Maybe some one had this issue before or know how tto do it, Please help me!!!

Comment: dbo? [Something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555789/difference-between-dbo-and-mdf-database)?

Comment: No, I think its a custom format. This file dbo created in C++ builder with fmOpenWrite

Comment: Maybe it's counting seconds since some epoch (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?